# DataSet and Primary Key with multiple columns

Tags: dataset, primary-key, multiple-columns

How Can I use Find method in DataSet that has Primary Key make of 3 Columns?

```
        dadSample.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StockBalance", conxMain)
        dadSample.FillSchema(dsSample, SchemaType.Source, "StockBalance")
        dadSample.Fill(dsSample, "Stock")

        Dim keyColStock(3) As DataColumn
        keyColStock(0) = dsSample.Tables("StockBalance").Columns("StockID")
        keyColStock(1) = dsSample.Tables("StockBalance").Columns("LocationID")
        keyColStock(2) = dsSample.Tables("StockBalance").Columns("StockBalanceUnitID")
        dsSample.Tables("StockBalance").PrimaryKey = keyColStkBal

        dRowCurrent = dsSample.Tables("StockBalance").Rows.Find("")
```

In Find parameter , which one I have to fill?
Please help me. Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search on an array, not a single value.

Something like:

```
Dim ObjectFindArray(2) as Object 
...
ObjectFindArray[0] = 
...
dRowCurrent = dsSample.Tables("StockBalance").Rows.Find(ObjectFindArray)
...
```

Comment: Thanks gbn! Your Answer is great!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a post on your problem - they suggest you pass an array of columns (for the key) and cast it to object[]

[Find with more than one columns in key](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=98071)